# Arduino HTTP Command - ESPEasy

Tags: wifi, http

I am new to Arduino and although I am starting with and creating some basic projects my end goal right now is to be able to turn my Sonoff on and off via a momentary switch attached to my Wifi enabled Arduino board (Particle Photon). I'm not looking for the code I would just like to pointed in the right direction.

I flashed my Sonoff so that it now runs ESPEasy and set it up so that I can control it from my browser using http://10.0.1.35/control?cmd=event,TurnOn to turn it on and http://10.0.1.35/control?cmd=event,TurnOff to turn it off. I have been reading about using POST or GET requests but none of the examples I find seem to send a similar command to how I currently have my Sonoff set up.

My question is what should I be looking at and reading about to be able to send these types of commands via the Arduino?

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. I'm thoroughly enjoying getting into coding but finding this step quite challenging to say the least!

Thanks!

Comment: Particle Photon is not Arduino. with Arduino you would use a WiFi library for your WiFi adapter. the Arduino WiFi libraries have examples

Comment: My apologies, I suppose it isn't, but I'm working on the basis that the solution will be the same between Arduino and the Photon board I'm using.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClient

Comment: Have you tried to perform a HTTP Get request with exactly the URLs, that you already used in your browser? The browser also simply does a Get request

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the heads up that the GET request was indeed the right way to go. I managed to work through this a bit today got the GET request to work. I also hooked up the button and got that to send the two requests on both press and release. I know this code is for the Photon but I hope it'll help someone else out

```
// TCPClient
#define LIB_DOMAIN "10.0.1.252"
TCPClient client;

// This constant won't change:
const int  buttonPin = D1;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int ledPin = D7;       // internal LED pin

// Variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Initialize D7 pin as output
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  // Initialize D1 pin as input with an internal pull-up resistor
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    // if the state has changed, turn on or off
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        //TCPClient
        client.connect(LIB_DOMAIN, 80);
        client.println("GET /control?cmd=event,TurnOff HTTP/1.0");
        client.println("Host:" LIB_DOMAIN);
        client.println("Content-Length: 0");
        client.println();
    } else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        //TCPClient
        client.connect(LIB_DOMAIN, 80);
        client.println("GET /control?cmd=event,TurnOn HTTP/1.0");
        client.println("Host:" LIB_DOMAIN);
        client.println("Content-Length: 0");
        client.println();
    }
    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
  // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonState = buttonState;

}
```